# jasperserver 4.7 and liferay 5.2 -- connection refused

Tags: liferay, portlet, jasperserver

I download liferay 5.2 (tomcat) with jasper server portlet, and jasper server 4.7 as well,  configure and install in seperate computer (liferay 5.2 and jasperserver 4.7) . I have gone through the readme file and configure portlet.xml at jasper portlet and applicationContext-security-web.xml at jasper server. portlet deployed successfully there is connection refused message. It's not connected with the report server (even after trusted ip).

Appriciate any help in advance

Comment: If you "just" downloaded Liferay 5.2.3, please keep in mind that it's 5 years old and unsupported. Rather download the current version 6.1.2 and try again with current software versions. If you want to integrate something into an existing portal, please upgrade first, then continue to add features to it.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf Kock for the reply ! We already have the beta 6.2 liferay. But jaspersoft didn't provide any portlet for 6.1 even (for community). For community edition jaspersoft 4.7 server provides the liferay 5.2 integration. (Things might be different for liferay commercial). I face 'connection refused' issue. I am worried about the trust between the two (liferay,jasper) might be a question, and requested a help. If I got the success then same I shall implement in the latest version.